# missing required architecture x86_64 in file

Tags: ios, architecture, xcode6, x86-64, static-linking

When linking an iOS app I have the following issue:

> (null): Ignoring file /Users/…../my_Lib.a, missing required
>   architecture x86_64 in file /Users/…/my_Lib.a (2 slices)

Seeing the message it seems like there is an issue with my_Lib.a.

After reading about similar problems on the net, I haven’t found any working solution at this point.

One detail I want to add is that I have a second project using this exact same library (my_Lib.a), which is perfectly working.
So there is nothing wrong with the library itself, only some settings are not right, probably inside the project.

Further more looking at the architecture settings on the two projects, they look pretty much the same.

When running lipo -info I get the following:

```
$ lipo -info my_Lib.a
Architectures in the fat file: my_Lib.a are: armv7 arm64
```

So what can I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please make the project settings as follows:

> Architectures: Standard architectures (armv7, arm64)

and

> Valid architectures: arm64 armv7s armv7

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but this is exactly the way it already is and I am having the problem.